# Authentication using Aspnet Roles : Access is denied when It should be allowed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, forms-authentication

I'm currently working on an Aspnet  MVC3 Razor application for management of some data. Access to application is controlled by authentication using forms.

I use ELMAH for error catching in order to treat them in a second time. Elmah provide an elmah.axd module which is located in root folder of the project in order to see errors.

These data must be private, that's why I wrote this rule in the web.config file :

```
 <location path="elmah.axd">
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
  </httpHandlers>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Dev"/>
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

This code allow users who are in 'dev' role (in my aspnet_usersinroles table) and deny all other users.

However, if I sign in with one user who having this role, access to the page is denied.

If I allow the same user using users authorization (see below), I can access to the page without problem.

```
<allow users="yohann.pansard@gmail.com"/>
```

I checked my Aspnet_usersinroles table several times and everything is good.

My roleManager looks good because I used these same roles in the application (eg Role.IsUserInRoles("foo", "reader")). Here is the configuration of my roleManager:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="app_demo" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

I think roles are not attributed to users but i'm not sure. Is it possible?

I probably forgot something, but I don't see what could be this element.

Is someone could help me please?

Comment: What is in your webconfig in applicationwide system.web section? Is there deny user="*" ?

Comment: In applicationwide system.web section I have <allow users="*" />

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check these link on how to secure Elmah + your configuration should look like

```
    <elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="true" />
  </elmah>
  <location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
      </httpHandlers>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Dev" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
      <!-- 
        See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
        more information on using ASP.NET authorization securing ELMAH.
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Dev" />
        <deny users="*" />  
      </authorization>
      -->
    </system.web>
```

Under the appsetting tag. You should also  update the correct values

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="true" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="Dev" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried, but the problem isn't solved. I don't think it's a problem with elmah configuration because, i tried with a simple html page and problem is the same. Is there a reason for users don't get their roles?